# How to use a predefined constant as a memory address?

Tags: assembly, constants, 6502, nes

I have a NES game in the making. I am defining several constants to help me with managing sprites. I have

```
spriteyposition = $0200
spritetile = $0201
spriteattribute = $0202
spritexposition = $0203
sprite1 = $00
sprite2 = $04
sprite3 = $08
sprite4 = $0c
sprite5 = $10
sprite6 = $14
sprite7 = $18
sprite8 = $1c
```

My use case is as follows:

I want to modify the y position of sprite 1

I do:

```
ldx sprite1
lda spriteyposition, x
adc #$8
sta spriteyposition, x
```

In my use case spriteyposition should be a memory pointer, but i have a feeling that the assembler is treating it as a regular number

How do I refer to spriteyposition as a memory address and not a number?

Comment: What are you hoping `lda spriteyposition, x` will do?  An indexed load into the accumulator, with the addressing mode using the `x` register plus `0x0200` as an immediate part of the address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In my use case `spriteyposition` should be a memory pointer, but i have a feeling that the assembler is treating it as a regular number

Your feeling is incorrect. This code assembles to the intended opcode BD (`LDA ABS,x`) -- there is no `IMM,x` addressing mode.

What is incorrect is

```
ldx sprite1
```

`sprite1` is defined as `$00`, so this ends up loading X with the value of the address `$0000`. What you want is `ldx #sprite1`.